# Android Canvas: Detecting faster dispatchTouchEvents

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

I have the following code which creates a pixel grid layout with a `spanCount` parameter:

```
class MyCanvasView(context: Context, val spanCount: Double) : View(context) {
    lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
    private lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap

    val rectangles = mutableListOf<RectF>()

    private lateinit var caller: CanvasFragmentListener

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)

        caller = context as CanvasFragmentListener

        if (::extraBitmap.isInitialized) extraBitmap.recycle()

        extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(extraBitmap)

        val scale = (w / spanCount)

        for (i in 0 until spanCount.toInt()) {
            for (i_2 in 0 until spanCount.toInt()) {
                val left = (i * scale).toFloat()
                val top = (i_2 * scale).toFloat()
                val rect = RectF(
                    left,
                    top,
                    left + scale.toFloat(),
                    top + scale.toFloat()
                )
                Log.d("MY_LOG", "LEFT: ${((i * scale).toFloat())} TOP: ${((i_2 * scale).toFloat())} ")

                rectangles.add(rect)
                extraCanvas.drawRect(
                    rect,
                    Paint().apply {
                        style = Paint.Style.FILL
                        color = Color.WHITE
                    })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun drawRectAt(x: Float, y: Float) {
        for (rect in rectangles) {
            if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                caller.onPixelTapped(this, rect)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y

        when (event.actionMasked) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                drawRectAt(x, y)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                drawRectAt(x, y)
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
    }
}
```

This canvas can detect swipe/touch events of the user, which means if the user drags their finger from top to bottom at a slow speed they will see the following:

(On the left, I did a very slow bottom-to-top swipe, and on the very right, I did a very fast bottom-to-top swipe. The swipes gradually get faster as you go along.)

[image]

As you may tell, the far right example looks very bad! There are many holes in between these pixels. It seems as though the `dispatchTouchEvent` isn't handling fast gestures so well.

If I open up any conventional pixel art editor and do the same as what I did in my app, there is no difference between how each line is rendered:

[image]

Even drawing a line in MS Paint with a very fast speed will yield a perfect result:

[image]

If anyone knows how I can achieve this on a Canvas please reply to this - the solution may be easy or it may be obvious - I'm new to Android Canvas so I don't really know. But for my pixel art app I want the user to be able to swipe fast and have it all rendered nicely, but I have a feeling this is going to be hard to implement and will require a lot of low level code, this guy even said you need to move to OpenGL ES to achieve this but Idk if this is true.

---

*Edit:*

Thanks to someone in the comments, the following code *improves* it by around 60-70%:

```
 val historySize = event.historySize
        val pointerCount = event.pointerCount

        for (h in 0 until historySize) {
            for (p in 0 until pointerCount) {
                drawRectAt(event.getHistoricalX(p, h), event.getHistoricalY(p, h))
            }
            for (p in 0 until pointerCount) {
                drawRectAt(event.getX(p), event.getY(p))
            }
        }
```

Really fast swipes look like the following *without* that block of code:

[image]

With the block of code added the situation significantly improved (and so have slower swipes):

[image]

I'm still looking for a solution which will make it 100% perfect, but I'm wondering if this is the furthest I'm going to get using `event.historySize` and `event.pointerCount`.

---

Drawing a line in between pixels gets me *very* close to the result:

[image]

The only problem is that the line is not pixelized in relation to the `spanCount` value.

[image]

In order to rasterize the line so it appears as though the user has drawn it, we could use Bresenham's line algorithm as someone had recommended in the **comments** which would look similar to the following:

[image]

This is probably how most pixel art editors handle faster swipes, although there absolutely no tutorials or resources as to how you would implement Bresenham's line algorithm in an Android app, so if anyone can supply me with some easy-to-learn resources that would be appreciated.

---

I am offering **150 reputation immediately** to anyone who can somehow assist in the implementation this feature that I want.

Comment: Hardware input rate is not infinite. The solution most paint programs probably use is to draw a line of pixels between the previous touch point and the most recent. If you try this with MSPaint for example and draw a very curved arc, you'll see that it looks faceted, like it's made up of several straight line segments.

Comment: @Tenfour04 please show me how do I learn this? have you got a link for a tutorial

Comment: It seems unlikely there's a tutorial on making a paint program. Kind of niche. My strategy would be to have a property that holds the coordinates of the previously received touch position. For each new drag-touch position, don't just mark the touched point, but mark all points in a line between the previous touch position and this one. You could look up a line drawing algorithm for that, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm I've tinkered with a pixel art program before and used the Bresenham algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you think my approach so far of drawing Rectangles is good? Or should I be drawing a line and converting that into pixels using an algorithm? That's also kind of what I'm confused about. Because I want to earn money from this pixel art editor, so I need it to be perfect implementation-wise. If u don't want to answer then no worries.

Comment: With Canvas I think maybe rectangles are the only way to draw a pixel art pixel. To draw an aliased line, you would use something to like the Bresenham algorithm to draw a set of pixels using rectangles at once. I suppose another strategy would be to draw your pixels to a Bitmap and draw the Bitmap to Canvas. I’m not sure which would perform better.

Comment: Hi guys I am bountying this cause I need a solution 4 my app and I haven't found any good examples of using `getHistoricalX()` online, cheers :)

Comment: There is some code [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#batching) under "Batching" that offers some further explanation. You would process the historical info in time order just as if they came in one at a time.

Comment: @Cheticamp the code improves it by around 60% but it's still not detecting really fast swipes well.

Comment: You may need to just draw lines between the points. That what it looks like the pixel art editor may be doing.

Comment: @Cheticamp how would I do that? Have you got a tutorial

Comment: See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawLine(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))

Comment: @Cheticamp I'll have a look

Comment: @Cheticamp any idea how I would pixelize the line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240114/discussion-between-tom-joney-and-cheticamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late reply: this was fixed by simply drawing a line in between points using Bresenham's line algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Motion events can combine rapid touches into a single event.  The X and Y are the latest position, the older ones are stored as historical points.  Use getHistoricalX() and getHistoricalY to get that data.  You'll need to use it to get a smooth line.

Comment: Have you got a tutorial for this?

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't accept this answer because there is no examples online as to how I would use `getHistoricalX()` or `getHistoricalY()`.